# Configuring HikariCP for the Play Framework to connect to Postgres over SSL?

Tags: postgresql, scala, ssl, playframework, hikaricp

I am trying to get the Play Framework to connect to Postgres database over SSL. SSL is configured with LetsEncrypt on Postgres.

Without SSL, Play has no problem connecting to the database. But with it, I get the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mainuser/.postgresql/root.crt (No such file or directory)
```

I need to mention that certificate files are placed under the directory `/etc/postgresql/13/main/`. The ssl connection to the database works just fine both locally and remotely outside Play.

The current `application.conf` includes:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/my_db?ssl=on"
db.default.username=${?DATABASE_USER}
db.default.password=${?DATABASE_PASSWORD}
db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery = "SELECT 1"


fixedConnectionPool = 5

database.dispatcher {
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  throughput = 1
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = ${fixedConnectionPool}
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to connect to this database, both locally and remotely over SSL. The official documentation

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems that your `root.crt` is not accessible by the Java process, have you checked the rights?

Comment: @GaëlJ The file didn’t exist in the first place. Why is Postgres trying to access it? The `.crt` files are placed under `/etc/postgresql/13/main`

Comment: The client needs a crt file too.  And in general it will be in a different location.  If your client and server are sharing crt files, they probably trust each other already, so then why use ssl in the first place?  If you want the client to use one in a different location than its custom, then you need to tell it to do that.

Comment: @jjanes Thank you for mentioning this. The Play framework is not running on SSL. It is running on apache2 and it relies on the encryption of communication through apache2. But it is actually Play itself which is supposed to access the database. On remote clients also, there will be Akka applications accessing the Postgres database. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to set the `sslrootcert` variable of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver in order to change the location of the certificate. I quote from the driver's manual:

> sslrootcert = String
>
> File name of the SSL root certificate. Defaults to defaultdir/root.crt
> where defaultdir is ${user.home}/.postgresql/ in *nix systems and
> %appdata%/postgresql/ on windows
>
> It can be a PEM encoded X509v3 certificate

See, for [example](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html), `https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html`. And while I haven't tried it, you should be able to add it as a further argument to your JDBC connection string, `db.default.url`, like

```
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/my_db?ssl=on&sslrootcert=/new/path/cert"
```

if the `application.conf` setting for it isn't obvious or non-existent.

Comment: Is the file  supposed to be owned by `postgres`? I downloaded letsencrypt’s `.pem` root certificate from [here](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/), and then converted it to `.crt`, then placed it under the `${user.home}/.postgresql/` directory and added the path to `application.conf`. Now, I get the error: `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`. I suspect it might be because this file is supposed to be accessed by `Play` rather than `postgres`

Comment: I suspected it might be because this file is supposed to be accessed by `Play` rather than `postgres`; yet, after returning the ownership to the `mainuser` nothing changed.

Comment: I'm not sure, what the problem is now. I would probably first try to make the file world-readable and see if it works at all this way. Then I'd restrict it back to what is really needed. Afterall, this is not the private key, but only the certificate, which in all likelihood isn't sensitive or you wouldn't have chosen letsencrypt, I assume. So, no harm is done by narrowing it down this way.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I was concerned with its getting replaced or rewritten. It seems like the problem is not the permission though.

Comment: The thing that finally solved the ssl problem was adding `sslmode=require` to the url. Now the problem is the rejection of the connection from `pg_hba.conf` which I think should not be related to this question. You can edit your answer and include it. Then I can accept the answer.

Comment: I also did [this](https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/ajouter-certificat-intermediaire-keystore-java.html) which might have played a role, since one of the intermediate certificates were not already added to the java keystore, which is the `cacerts` file under `$JAVA_HOME`